# Where is the home directory

Tags: home-directory

How do I copy and paste some thing into my home directory can't find it please  help  I have been trying to update to 14.04 and I know I need to change something in the home directory I just can't find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### User bob's home

`/home/bob`

`~bob`

### User root's home

`/root`

### Current user's (your) home

`/home/[your username]`

or shortcut:

`~`

> Thanks to @musiKk for telling me about `~bob`

Comment: And for the sake of completion: Shortcut to bob's home: `~bob`.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `/home/$USER`, because you can set an account to have any directory, including one outside of `/home` or without the username in it at all, as a home directory. Use `~`, `~user`, or `$HOME`.

Answer (score 5):

in a console you just type:

```
cd
```

then you type:

```
pwd
```

after pwd command, appears your answer, that is your home.

Answer (score 1):

When I click on the file browser cabinet icon on the left hand side, it open into the Home directory automatically. There are also options to navigate to the Home folder from there, if for any reason you are directed to another location/folder.

[Home folder](http://www.alansitsolutions.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Ubuntu-One-Home-Folder1.png)

Or you could try typing $HOME in the File Manager, that should open it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
echo $USER
```

shows your user name. And the home folder is always at `/`. Therefore:

```
cd /home/$USER
```

or

```
cd $HOME
```

or simpler

```
cd ~
```